# How to stub an exception multiple times in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I want to stub a method call 40 times with an exception and then with a real object. As far I can see, the Mockito 1.10.8's `thenThrow()` method accepts n number of Throwables:

```
OngoingStubbing<T> thenThrow(Throwable... throwables);
```

Therefore, I thought I could do the following.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyObjectTest
{
    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_MOCKS)
    private Mama mama;

    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
    private Papa papa;

    private MyObject _instance;

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        _instance = new MyObject(papa, mama);

        Throwable[] exceptions = new Throwable[41];

        Arrays.fill(exceptions, 0, 40, new ConnectionException("exception message"));

        when(papa.getMapper().map(anyString())).thenThrow(exceptions).thenReturn(new MyMap());

        verify(papa, times(41)).getMapper().map(anyString());
    }
}
```

However, when I run this test I get the following.

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
>   Cannot stub with null throwable!
>       at MyObjectTest.test(MyObjectTest.java:105)

MyObjectTest.java:105 is the line where the stubbing takes place.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: If you replace with `thenThrow(new ConnectionException("exception message"))` - does it still throw MockitoException?

Comment: No, it does not. Actually, one of the other tests in the same test class does that and it passes neatly.

Comment: I could not understand what would you need. Could you write more about what you expect?

Comment: @Fariba I want to test if papa.getMapper().map() method is called 41 times. Because, my class under test calls this method as long as a ConnectionException is thrown, but maximum 40 times.

Comment: @bluesman80 I would check your `exceptions` object is being populated properly with Arrays.fill(). Ensure that the values inside the array are not null

Comment: I am thinking how to do this, may be this link can give you some idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3498072/how-to-only-throw-exception-when-the-mocked-method-is-called-for-the-first-time

Comment: @JLewkovich Good point, thank you. Fariba, I have already checked every question close to mine in this site. But, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this exception because you have a `Throwable[]` with 41 elements, but you only fill 40 of them with an actual `ConnectionException` value. The last one is `null`.

[`thenThrow`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/stubbing/OngoingStubbing.html#thenThrow%28java.lang.Throwable...%29) does not accept throwing `null` ([which would cause a `NullPointerException` to be thrown instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17576922/why-can-i-throw-null-in-java)).

Your array should only contain 40 elements

```
Throwable[] exceptions = new Throwable[40];
```

Comment: I can't believe that I have been struggling with this for hours! Turns out to be a foolish mistake. Thank you very much!